# python - distribute values to different lists (algorithm)

Tags: python, algorithm

**Description**

I have a problem with a project study in my university. Here is a quick example:

[image: python - distribute values to different lists]

- There are locations (sources - on the left) with an specific amount of items.
- These sources are connected to some (not all) destination locations (on the right).
- The destinations have an minimum amount they should receive
- Especially the "green" one (`Dest. X`) because it is prioritized. It is more important to fulfill the mininmum amount of this destination than of other destinations if there are too less items from the sources.
- Some destinations have an maximum amount of items they can take.

**Problem / approach**

I've already started with a python script to handle that. It creates `sources` and `destinations` with random amounts of items. But I don't know how to distribute all items considerung the `mininum amounts`, the `maximum_amounts`, the prioritization and of course the fact, that not all sources are connected to all destinations.

Any approaches are welcome, preferably with a few lines of code :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

```
import random
nums = [100]+[200]+[500]
#used to check if the vars have been chekd b4
xc = 0
yc = 0
zc = 0

#define Sources:
a = random.choice(nums) #I decided to define them at random
b = random.choice(nums)
c = random.choice(nums)
d = random.choice(nums)

#Define Destinations:
x = 0 #min: 500
y = 0 #min: 100 #max: 200
z = 0 #min: 300

#prioritize:
pri = 0
if a+b+c < 500:
    pri = 1

#fill x:
if pri == 0:
    if a >= 500 and xc == 0:
        x += a
        a -= a
        xc = 1
    if b >= 500 and xc == 0:
        x += b
        b -= b
        xc = 1
    if c >= 500 and xc == 0:
        x += c
        c -= c
        xc = 1
if pri == 1:
    x += a+b+c
    a -= a
    b -= b
    c -= c
#we didnt test for d bcus its not cond

#fill y:
if b >= 100 and b <= 200 and yc == 0:
    y += b
    b -= b
    yc = 1
if c >= 100 and b <= 200 and yc == 0:
    y += c
    c -= c
    yc = 1
if d >= 100 and b <= 200 and yc == 0:
    y += d
    d -= d
    yc = 1

#fill z:
if a >= 300 and zc == 0:
    z += a
    a -= a
    zc = 1
if c >= 300 and zc == 0:
    z += c
    c -= c
    zc = 1
if d >= 300 and zc == 0:
    z += d
    d -= d
    zc = 1

#test if it is filled:
print("X: "+"{}".format(x)+"/500+")
print("Y: "+"{}".format(y)+"/100_200")
print("Z: "+"{}".format(z)+"/300+")
#X:
if x >= 500:
    print("X filled correctly!")
if x < 500:
    print("X not filled!")
#Y:
if y >= 100 and y <= 200:
    print("Y filled correctly!")
if y < 100:
    print("Y not filled!")
if y > 200:
    print("Y over-filled!")
#Z:
if z >= 300:
    print("Z filled correctly!")
if z < 300:
    print("Z not filled!")

input()#waits for you to end it manually
```

Sometimes X won't be filled despite one value being 500 because d is not connected to X (d can be 500 sometimes)

Sorry if im wrong!  I'm not too good at math and It took me a while to (hopefully) understand what the OP wanted.
Hope i helped in at least SOME aspects haha.  (had to use a lot of algebra)

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort! It helped me to understand how to solve the problem. I probably missed that the sources and destinations may vary. I'll try to adapt your version for any amount of sources and destinations (max. 100) and let you all know. :)

Comment: It was fun making this, Happy I could help!